# combine two for loops in to fill same dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to get two different merchants from a list of dictionaries with priority to merchants who have prices,if no two different merchants are found with prices, merchant 1 or 2 prices are to be filled with data from list,if list is not enough merchant 1 or 2 should be None.

I.e the for loop will return two merchants,priority to merchants who have prices, if that is not enough to fill merchants (1 or 2) get merchants with no prices.finally if still merchant 1 or 2 not created fill them with None value.

here is the code I have so far, it does the job but I believe it can be combined in a more Pythonic way.

```
import csv
with open('/home/timmy/testing/example/example/test.csv') as csvFile:
    reader=csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for row in reader:
        dummy_list.append(row)
item=dict()
index = 1
for merchant in dummy_list:
    if merchant['price']:
        if index==2:
            if item['merchant_1']==merchant['name']:
                continue
        item['merchant_%d'%index] = merchant['name']
        item['merchant_%d_price'%index] = merchant['price']
        item['merchant_%d_stock'%index] = merchant['stock']
        item['merchant_%d_link'%index] = merchant['link']
        if index==3:
            break
        index+=1

for merchant in dummy_list:
    if index==3:
        break
    if index<3:
        try:
            if item['merchant_1']==merchant['name']:
                continue
        except KeyError:
            pass
        item['merchant_%d'%index] = merchant['name']
        item['merchant_%d_price'%index] = merchant['price']
        item['merchant_%d_stock'%index] = merchant['stock']
        item['merchant_%d_link'%index] = merchant['link']
        index+=1

while index<3:
    item['merchant_%d'%index] = ''
    item['merchant_%d_price'%index] = ''
    item['merchant_%d_stock'%index] = ''
    item['merchant_%d_link'%index] = ''
    index+=1
print(item)
```

here is the contents of the csv file:

```
price,link,name,stock
,https://www.samsclub.com/sams/donut-shop-100-ct-k-cups/prod19381344.ip,Samsclub,
,https://www.costcobusinessdelivery.com/Green-Mountain-Original-Donut-Shop-Coffee%2C-Medium%2C-Keurig-K-Cup-Pods%2C-100-ct.product.100297848.html,Costcobusinessdelivery,
,https://www.costco.com/The-Original-Donut-Shop%2C-Medium-Roast%2C-K-Cup-Pods%2C-100-count.product.100381350.html,Costco,
57.99,https://www.target.com/p/the-original-donut-shop-regular-medium-roast-coffee-keurig-k-cup-pods-108ct/-/A-13649874,Target,Out of Stock
10.99,https://www.target.com/p/the-original-donut-shop-dark-roast-coffee-keurig-k-cup-pods-18ct/-/A-16185668,Target,In Stock
,https://www.homedepot.com/p/Keurig-Kcup-Pack-The-Original-Donut-Shop-Coffee-108-Count-110030/204077166,Homedepot,Undertermined
```

Comment: Hi, can you please give us an example of the CSV file structure ? Just top 5 rows or so should be enough. (do it by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56288827/edit) your question, not in the comments please) Thank you !

Comment: @reportgunner I have placed a sample of CSV file, do you mean how the CSV is getting filled?

Comment: oh sorry I missed it :)

Comment: Here is what I have understood: 1. Find 2 different merchant with prices. 2. If less than 2 merchant with prices fill the list with other merchants with no price 3. if still less than 2 merchants, fill with None. Is that ok?

Comment: @SergeBallesta exactly, it must return two merchants even if empty (filled with None), with priority to prices, then no prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you only want to keep at most 2 merchants, I would process the csv only once keeping separately a list of merchant with prices and a list of merchant without prices, stopping as soon as 2 merchant with prices have been found.

After that loop, I would concatenate those 2 list and a list of two empty merchants and take the first 2 elements of that. That will be enough to guarantee your requirements of 2 distinct merchants with priority to those having prices. Finaly, I would use that to fill the `item` dict.

Code would be:

```
import csv

with open('/home/timmy/testing/example/example/test.csv') as csvFile:
    reader=csv.DictReader(csvFile)

    names_price = set()
    names_no_price = set()
    merchant_price = []
    merchant_no_price = []
    item = {}

    for merchant in reader:
        if merchant['price']:
            if not merchant['name'] in names_price:
                names_price.add(merchant['name'])
                merchant_price.append(merchant)
                if len(merchant_price) == 2:
                    break;
        else:
            if not merchant['name'] in names_no_price:
                names_no_price.add(merchant['name'])
                merchant_no_price.append(merchant)

    void = { k: '' for k in reader.fieldnames}
    merchant_list = (merchant_price + merchant_no_price + [void, void.copy()])[:2]

    for index, merchant in enumerate(merchant_list, 1):
        item['merchant_%d'%index] = merchant['name']
        item['merchant_%d_price'%index] = merchant['price']
        item['merchant_%d_stock'%index] = merchant['stock']
        item['merchant_%d_link'%index] = merchant['link']
```

Comment: this gives a `KerError` in the second for loop,did you test it? (assuming t is the path)

Comment: @programmerwiz32 Oops! As I do not have your file on my system I tested it with a memory file and t is a string containing the lines you showed in the question. And I forgot to change it back to the original `open` command when I pasted it here. Fixed now.